grub does not see the microsd card
I have a laptop with Ubuntu on its main drive (/dev/nvme0). I am trying to get it to dual boot another Linux install, which is physically located on a microsd card. When booted into Ubuntu, I see the microsd card as /dev/sda, with the other Linux on /dev/sda1 (boot EFI partition) and /dev/sda2 (main filesystem.)
Now my problem is that grub simply does not see that microsd card at all. If I drop into grub console by hitting 'c' during boot, I see the main drive as (hd0) and that's it.
I tried to add
insmod scsi
insmod ahci
insmod ehci

And I think it worked for me in the past (I tried to do this a couple of years ago, but I don't recall the details.)
At present, not only does the microsd card fail to appear, but executing them makes (hd0) disappear too, leading to various other errors.
Secure boot is off, fast boot is off.
Typing  nativedisk in the grub console has the same effect (hd0 disappears and no new devices appear).
Anything else I should try?

I think you need the usbms module too, assuming it is not loaded yet. (Not sure if you need to explicitly load the usb one either.) (The ahci one is definitely irrelevant. The scsi one? Maybe.)

Actually, after a second thought, if you can't see it without nativedisk and/or loading the relevant modules, it could be a problem in your UEFI / BIOS. (But I suppose if the "native" drivers work for the card, you can load them inside the corresponding boot entry...) It is probably normal that after nativedisk the nvme drive is gone, since there are no native driver in grub for nvme drives, apparently. And probably you can't use both types of driver either.

Either a typo or a misunderstanding.  /dev/sda, /dev/sda1, and /dev/sda2 are all on the same "disk", so "I see the microsd card as /dev/sda, with the other Linux on /dev/sda1 (boot EFI partition) and /dev/sda2 (main filesystem.)" cannot be correct.

@waltinator he really just means that this "other Linux" is on the card that is /dev/sda. with the other Linux on /dev/sda1 (boot EFI partition) and /dev/sda2 (main filesystem.) is apparently talking about the partitioning of the card / this other Linux. (yeah, which is sort of irrelevant in this question)

@waitinator yes, I just mean that the sd card is partitioned into two partitions and I can't see either the partitions or the card, with all module permutations I tried.

Loading usbms does not help. One more complication is that some insmod commands give me an error Disk (hd0,gpt7) not found. Does it mean that some of these modules are loaded from the partition on /dev/nvme0 and need to be loaded in specific order, before it disappears?

Does it mean that some of these modules are loaded from the partition on /dev/nvme0 and need to be loaded in specific order, before it disappears? Yes, maybe you'll have to make grub-install or so to embed the modules in its "image", but probably you can't stop them from being loaded right away, which means you won't be able to boot Ubuntu.
